# Why ES6 Fiddle doesn't overwrite named argument?

Tags: javascript

This function doesn't overwrite `num2` with the statement `arguments[1]` when I run it in ES6 Fiddle; but it does in Firefox Console.

```
function doAdd(num1, num2) {
arguments[1] = 10;
alert(arguments[0] + num2);
}
```

Is is possible that Firefox does't implement ES6 in its console?

Comment: `arguments` isn't an ES6 feature, so I doubt that's the issue. In fact, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) it's been around since Javascript 1.1. Sounds more like a bug in ES6 Fiddle to me; I get the same behavior in Chrome's dev console as you do in the Firefox dev console, which makes me think that's the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ES6. It's just that modifying the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) won't change the parameters in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (which is a good thing). ES6 Fiddle seems to imply strict mode, just like ES6 modules do.